# Bash Profile Coloring

Tags: shell, ls, .bash-profile

I would like to make a few changes to my bash profile.  Changes I would like include:

- Coloring Files:  I would like files with the execute permission bit set to be colored green.
- I would like to know how to assign different file extensions to different colors when the `ls` command is run.
- I would like ls to append an `*` to the end of file names with the execution bit set.
- I would like to color setuid executable files a different color.

How would I implement this using my `.bashrc` file?

Comment: Most of it can be achieved with `alias ls='ls --color=auto'`.

Comment: alias ls='ls -F' for appending an '*' to executables

Answer (score 5):

Summarizing from the other suggestions: 
Put this in your `.bashrc` (or preferably, `.bash_aliases`):

```
alias ls="ls -F --color=auto"
```

Also, a good read would be `man dircolors`.